# How to read text file, also reading coordinates of beginning of each word/number/punctuation mark (or just symbols)?

Tags: c#, text-files

For example, i have text file:

```
type beg = record
    str: string[25];
    b: boolean; 
    lon: longint;
end;
```

I turn it into linked list:

```
LinkedList<string> inputText = new LinkedList<string>(
    Regex.Split(text, @"\s+|(?!^|-)(?=\p{P})|(?<=\p{P})(?<!-)(?!$)"));
```

It will look like:

```
type => beg => = => record => str => : => str => ...
```

How can i also create list of coordinates (line and column) of each element of this text file?

For my example it will look like:

```
1,1 => 1,6 => 1,10 => 1,12 => 2,5 => ...
```

It's easy to find line number as i can read file line by line, but here is problem with column. Let's see:

```
    str: string[25]; //here is 4 free spaces before text
```

My regex will split it into:

```
str => : => string => [ => 25 => ] => ;
```

So if i try to figure out coordinates of each element by it's length here will be problem with free spaces between elements.

I can read file symbol by symbol, but maybe here is some better solution?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Post some lines of your input file (verbatim), some lines of required output. Explain what yopu want to do in simple words. What should this mega-regexp do? Give your helpers a chance to help you.

Comment: each match from the regex will include the character offset and length for the match, so that gets you halfway there. you would need to also index the lines to character offsets, so that you can map the raw character offsets to line+offset pairs. Alternatively, you might find it easier to read line by line and just apply the regex to each line individually. You should at least try _something_; otherwise it seems kind of like you're just asking someone else to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I just got it. I need to split each line by free space to know, where it is and only after this use my regex to split words and numbers from punctuacion marks.